# why setAtrribute and removeAttribute is not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-manipulation

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2Y80.png) App.js

```js
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const li = document.createElement('li');

ul.append(li);

li.innerText = 'X-Men';

li.setAttribute('id', 'main-heading');
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1 id="main-heading">Favorite Movie Franchise</h1>
    <ul>
        <li class="list-items">
            <span>Neo</span>
            The Matrix
        </li>
        <li class="list-items">
            Star Wars
        </li>
        <li class="list-items">
            Harry Potter
        </li>
        <li class="list-items">
            Lord of Rings
        </li>
        <li class="list-items">
            Marvel
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have added a image of my Html page where heading is showing i want to set the attribute of 'X-Men' same as the h1 element which is "Favorite Movie Franchise". For that,I am trying to use `setAttribute` method on a dynamically created `li` element,
but it's not working. I am expecting the `li` element to have the same attribute as `main-heading`.
Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question lacks enough detail for anyone to give help that is likely to be useful. Please read the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [ask] for guidance on editing your question to make it possible and easy for people to help you.

Comment: I'm not seeing "main heading" in your code, and the code you postd should work fine, but there won't be an id because you add and then remove it immediately?

Comment: In particular I don't understand how you are determining if this is working or not, or where *main-heading* is supposed to come from.

Comment: "but it's not working in Chrome" — Are you mentioning Chrome because this is a Chrome-specific problem? Or is it because you have only tested using Chrome?

Comment: @Quentin Please check again, i have added the all contents of code, also as i am running this in chrome so i mentioned it is not working in chrome.

Comment: I still don't understand how you are determining if the code is working or not. (There are other issues with your question, but that's the biggest one.). You've provided code, but not explained what you expect to see in your browser or your debugger or your whatever that would tell you if it was working or not.

Comment: Yes, you are Right, I have attached a Image also

Comment: Your edit doesn't really help. "I am expecting the li element to have the same attribute as 'main-heading'." — What are you doing / where are you looking to determine what attribute the li has?

Comment: @RidhiRajput — There is no image attached to your question.

Comment: The issue is that you want it to look the same, so those definitions are in your `css`. If adding the same ID does not work then in all likelihood it is targetting the `h1`. You should duplicate neither (you shouldn't have more than 1 `h1` element, or 1 element with the same `id` on a page). Your solution is probably in CSS.

Comment: I don't understand how you are determining what attributes an element has based on what the rendered page looks like. (The code you've provided doesn't render the same way as that picture either. It's important to provide a [mcve]. I refer you back to my very first comment on this question.)

Comment: I know, but it should work, I am following a tutorial. And there At 22:56 min , it is working fine. Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fb2aPlgoys&list=PLWKjhJtqVAbleDe3_ZA8h3AO2rXar-q2V&index=2

Comment: I've edited your question so that your code is now a snippet that can be run directly from your question. It seems to work fine from what I can tell.  The `<li id="main-heading">` is added to the list

Comment: I have added the exact minute of tutorial.

Comment: You want every <li> like this <li id="main-heading">your content</li> or only last <li> like this <li id="main-heading">X-Men</li>, I am not clear

Comment: Keep in mind that an ID in HTML is meant to be unique, that means it can only exist one time for an entire document.  If the `<h1>` has an ID of  `id="main-heading"` it's not valid to also use that same ID for this new `<li>` element.

Comment: exactly right @Chris Barr

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.